# Cakephp 3.1 REST - Filtering data

Tags: rest, cakephp

I have setup my application for REST access as per documentation. The default routes are working well. I am able to retrieve, update and delete records, however, I am not sure how I could filter data sending parameters to the controller. I wonder if I can do that using querystring or if there is a better way to accomplish that. Please can someone give me directions?

Answer (score 1):

Reads about the [Request object in the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request). And use the [Search Plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) for filtering.

The search plugin comes with a lot of documentation that explains how to use it as well.

Your question is so generic that a proper answer would end up in a whole article - which I'm obviously not going to write, there is enough information available  on HTTP requests and query params. Use Google or read these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages
- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Request.html

Comment: Appreciate the information. The plugin seems very interesting. This answer my question. Thank you very much!